# Can we solve the following differential equation using the method of substitution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do we solve the differential equation, $\sec x\dfrac{dy}{dx}=y+\sin x$, by the method of substitution?

$$\sec x\frac{dy}{dx}=y+\sin x$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=y\cos x+\sin x \cos x $$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = y\cos x + \sin x\cos x
$$
$$
dy = y(\cos x\,dx) + \sin x(\cos x\,dx)
$$
$$
dy =y\,du+ u\,du
$$
$$
\frac{dy}{du} = y + u
$$
$$
\frac{dy}{du} - y = u
$$
$$
e^{-u}\frac{dy}{du} - e^{-u} y = e^{-u}u
$$
$$
\frac{d}{du}\left( e^{-u}  y \right) = ue^{-u}
$$
Now antidifferentiate both sides, etc.  (For the expression on the right side, integrate by parts.)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Assume that the function $z$ solves $z'(x)=-\cos(x)z(x)$, then one must solve the equation $-z(x)y'(x)=z'(x)(y(x)+\sin(x))$, that is, $(z(x)y(x))'=-z'(x)\sin(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the integrating factor technique.
$$ \sec(x) \frac{dy}{dx}= y + \sin(x) \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{dy}{dx}-\cos(x)y = \sin(x)\cos(x) $$
Hence $\mu = \exp(\int -\cos(x) dx) = \exp(-\sin(x))$. Multiply by $\mu$ to see
$$ d(\mu y) = \mu \sin(x)\cos(x) dx $$
Make the substitution $v = \mu y$ and that ought to do it.